# How to add data to an existing cell in Power Automate

Tags: excel, power-automate

Power automate to append data to an existing cell in Excel Online

Can someone help me adjust my
Flow.

**OBJECTIVE**

When a new event is *added* it *inserts a row* into my excel table with the id subject and start time with ISO 8601.

When an event is *updated* I want to add the updated start time to the existing row. So the cell would have the original and updatated start time(s).

It’s mostly done I think there is just something small Im missing.

**FLOW**

Trigger: Outlook event updated/added/deleted

Condition 3: actionType updated

If yes - list rows present in table (plugged in my table and I have date time as iso 8601)

Apply to each value

Update a row 2

- this is where I am getting stuck. Can someone provide an expression that will append the updated start time ? I have it configured so that it is editing the right row just it replaces the existing value.

Comment: Before you do the update, get the data for the existing row and concatenate the original data with the new data before writing back to the row.